# Why is this Xquery expression returning a null value?

Tags: xpath, xquery

I want to get the maximum value for an attribute. I have the following statement:

> let $posts := doc("Posts.xml")/posts/row[./@OwnerUserId = $user/@Id]
>
> let $maxScore := fn:max(xs:integer($posts/row/@Score))

When I want to return maxScore, it shows up as an empty value. Upon further tinkering, the following:

> Return $posts/row/@Score

Also shows up as empty, even though I know each row has a 'Score' attribute

I've been fighting with this for over an hour, any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting the `row` elements that meet the criteria of your predicate. So, the `$posts` variable will have a sequence of `row` elements.

If you want to select the `@Score` from each of the `row` elements in the `$posts` variable, your XPath should be: `$posts/@Score`

It would be less confusing if you named the variable `$rows`.

Or, change the XPath to actually select `posts` elements:

```
let $posts := doc("Posts.xml")/posts[row/@OwnerUserId = $user/@Id]
let $maxScore := fn:max(xs:integer($posts/row/@Score))
```